# Let $K/\mathbb{F}_2$ be the splitting field of the polynomial $x^{17}-1$. Determine $[K:\mathbb{F}_2]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Mainly, I would like to check if I am correct.  Over $\mathbb{Q}$, the result is shown in Sec. 13.4 or 13.6 of *Dummit and Foote*.  I think the result is essentially the same here.

Since $x-1$ is a root in $\mathbb{F}_2$, factor that out.  This leaves: $\frac{x^{17}-1}{x-1} = x^{16}+x^{15}+ \dots + x + 1$, which is irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_2$.  Therefore this is the minimal polynomial of $\zeta_{17}$ (the primitive 17th root of unity) over $\mathbb{F}_2$, so $[K:\mathbb{F}_2] = 16$.

Is this correct?  It seems rather straightforward, which makes me suspicious.

Thanks

---

Edit:  [Related Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/462298/determine-the-degree-of-the-splitting-field-for-fx-x15-1?rq=1).

In the question I linked above, the argument is as follows:  The splitting field will be $\mathbb{F}_{2^r}$ for the smallest $r$ such that there are elements of order $17$.  The order of the multiplicative group of $\mathbb{F}_{2^r}$ is $2^r-1$.  The smallest $r$ such that $17 |2^r-1$ is $r = 8$.  This would suggest that the polynomial above could be factored (I believe the factors are $x^8+x^7+x^6+x^4+x^2+x+1$ and $x^8+x^5+x^4+x^3+1$).

Comment: How do you show that $x^{16}+x^{15}+\ldots+1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_2$?

Comment: In this case you could just test both elements.  Both evaluate to $1 \neq 0$

Comment: I've changed my mind.  I think the answer may actually be 8.  I'm going to try to write that up.

Comment: Steve: that just means that it has no _linear_ factors.  That doesn't imply irreducibility over $\mathbb{F}_2$, any more than e.g. not having any integer roots implies irreducibility over $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Yeah, thanks.  I realized that after I sent my reply.  I've edited the original post.

Answer (score 0):

The solution you suggest in your edit is correct.